# Commit Pycharm virtual environment / generate venv by script

Tags: git, pycharm

Pycharm uses a virtual environment where a replicate of the original python binary and including packages resides.

This whole environment does consume a lot of space having a git-repository in mind.

The most obvious thing is to don't commit the the whole virtual environment. But if I do so, a coworker has the pain to run all the pip-commands in the pycharm gui again and I need to maintain setup instructions for him.

Is it possible for pycharm to just generate a script preparing the workspace by running pip commands?

This script only could be checked in and my repository admin would be very happy =)!

Comment: if you are looking for pip installations you can simply do `pip3 freeze >> filename`. This will copy your dependencies into the file. To install it you can use `pip3 install -r filename`.

Comment: this is kind of really great!